# Android FireBase - Connect to Game Service Leaderboard

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-play-games

I have made a login activity using firebase to connect with google. The user can login without problems Now I want to show a leaderboard on another activity however, when I check if the user is logged in and I try to show the leaderboard I get the error:

> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient
>   must be connected.

How can I connect `GoogleApiClient` using firebase? I have tried using `mGoogleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);` but this also does not work.

here my code:

```
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_achievements);


                // Configure Google Sign In
                GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                        .requestEmail()
                        .build();

                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                                // connection failed, should be handled
                            }
                        })
                        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                        .build();

                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

                mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        if (user != null) {
                            // User is signed in
                            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

     ////// is crashing googleapiclient not connected

startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient,
                                    getString(R.string.leaderboard_la_classifica)), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD); 

                        } else {
                            // User is signed out
                        }
                        // ...
                    }
                };

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin for more details.

When building the client, you need to use GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.fragment_firebase_games_signin);

     String webclientId = getString(R.string.web_client_id);

    GoogleSignInOptions options =
            new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestServerAuthCode(webclientId)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .requestIdToken()
                    .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, options)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .build();

}
```

Then to start the explicit sign-in start the signIn Intent:

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent =
         Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

You should also use an automanaged client, or simply call `mGoogleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);` in `onStart()` and disconnect in `onStop()`.

In onActivityResult, handle the result of the explicit sign-in intent:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            completeFirebaseAuth(acct);

            // At this point, the Games API can be called.

        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Completing the Firebase authentication:

```
private void completeFirebaseAuth(GoogleSignInAccount  acct) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new
                    OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                    }
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

The other situation you need to handle is the silent sign-in, which happens when resuming an app:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    // Handle the silent sign-in case.

    if (mGoogleApiClient.hasConnectedApi(Games.API)) {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(
                            @NonNull GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                        if (googleSignInResult.isSuccess()) {
                            completePlayGamesAuth(
                                    googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount());
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error with silentSignIn: " +
                                    googleSignInResult.getStatus());
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```